# How to erase "forwarded message" title and unwanted content from body of Enron emails?

Tags: python, email, nltk, text-processing

I am trying to append all the bodies of Enron Emails in one file so that I could process the text of these emails by eliminating Stop words and splitting it into sentences with NLTK.
My problem is with forwarded and replied messages, I am not sure how to clean them.
This is my code so far:

```
    import os, email, sys, re,nltk, pprint 
    from email.parser import Parser

    rootdir = '/Users/art/Desktop/maildir/lay-k/elizabeth'
    #function that appends all the body parts of Emails
    def email_analyse(inputfile,  email_body):
        with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
        data = f.read()

        email = Parser().parsestr(data)

        email_body.append(email.get_payload())
    #end of function
    #defining a list that will contain bodies
    email_body = []
    #call the function email_analyse for every function in directory
    for directory, subdirectory, filenames in  os.walk(rootdir):
        for filename in filenames:
            email_analyse(os.path.join(directory, filename),  email_body )
    #the stage where I clean the emails

    with open("email_body.txt", "w") as f:
        for val in email_body:
            if(val):
                val = val.replace("\n", "")
                val = val.replace("=01", "")
                #for some reason I had many of ==20 and =01 in my text
                val = val.replace("==20", "")
                f.write(val)
                f.write("\n")
```

This is the partial output:
    `Well, with the photographer and the band, I would say we've pretty much outdone our budget! Here's the information on the photographer. I have a feeling for some of the major packages we could negotiate at least a couple of hours at the rehearsal dinner. I have no idea how much this normally costs, but he isn't cheap!---------------------- Forwarded by Elizabeth Lay/HOU/AZURIX on 09/13/99 07:34 PM ---------------------------acollins@reggienet.com on 09/13/99 05:37:37 PMPlease respond to acollins@reggienet.com To: Elizabeth Lay/HOU/AZURIX@AZURIXcc:      Subject:    Denis Reggie Wedding PhotographyHello Elizabeth:Congratulations on your upcoming marriage!  I am Ashley Collins, Mr.Reggie's Coordinator.  Linda Kessler forwarded your e.mail address to me sothat I may provide you with information on photography coverage for Mr.Reggie's wedding photography.`
So the result is not a pure text at all. Any ideas on how to do it right?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at regular expressions to parse the forwarded and reply text because the format should be consistent throughout the corpus.

For deleting the forwarded text, you could use a regex like this:

```
-{4,}(.*)(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s*(PM|AM)
```

Which will match all the content between four or more hyphens and the time in the format XX:XX:XX PM. Matching 3 dashes would probably work fine, too. We just want to avoid matching hyphens and em-dashes in the email body. You can play around with this regex and write your own for matching To and Subject headers at this link: https://regex101.com/r/VGG4bu/1/

You can also look at section 3.4 of the NLTK book, which talks about regular expressions in Python: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html

Good luck! This sounds like an interesting project.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still interested in this problem, I've created a pre-processing script specifically for the Enron dataset. You'll notice that a new email will always start with the tag 'subject:', I implemented a function which removes all text to the left of this tag, and only on the last 'subject:' tag to remove all forwarded messages. Specific code:

```
# Cleaning content column
df['content'] = df['content'].str.rsplit('Subject: ').str[-1] 
df['content'] = df['content'].str.rsplit(' --------------------------- ').str[-1]
```

Overall script, if interested:

```
# Importing the dataset, and defining columns
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('enron_05_17_2015_with_labels_v2.csv', usecols=[2,3,4,13], dtype={13:str})

# Building a count of how many people are included in an email
df['Included_In_Email'] = df.To.str.count(',')
df['Included_In_Email'] = df['Included_In_Email'].apply(lambda x: x+1)

# Dropping any NaN's, and emails with >15 recipients
df = df.dropna()
df = df[~(df['Included_In_Email'] >=15)]

# Seperating remaining emails into a line-per-line format
df['To'] = df.To.str.split(',')
df2 = df.set_index(['From', 'Date', 'content', 'Included_In_Email']) 
['To'].apply(pd.Series).stack()
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2.columns = ['From','To','Date','content', 'Included_In_Email']

# Renaming the new column, dropping unneeded column, and changing indices
del df2['level_4']
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {0: 'To'})
df2 = df2[['Date','From','To','content','Included_In_Email']]
del df

# Cleaning email addresses
df2['From'] = df2['From'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip("frozenset"))
df2['To'] = df2['To'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip("frozenset"))
df2['From'] = df2['From'].str.strip("<\>(/){?}[:]*, ")
df2['To'] = df2['To'].str.strip("<\>(/){?}[:]*, ")
df2['From'] = df2['From'].str.replace("'", "")
df2['To'] = df2['To'].str.replace("'", "")
df2['From'] = df2['From'].str.replace('"', "")
df2['To'] = df2['To'].str.replace('"', "")

# Acccounting for users having different emails
email_dict = pd.read_csv('dict_email.csv')    
df2['From'] = df2.From.replace(email_dict.set_index('Old')['New'])
df2['To'] = df2.To.replace(email_dict.set_index('Old')['New'])
del email_dict

# Removing emails not containing @enron
df2['Enron'] = df2.From.str.count('@enron')
df2['Enron'] = df2['Enron']+df2.To.str.count('@enron')
df2 = df2[df2.Enron != 0]
df2 = df2[df2.Enron != 1]
del df2['Enron']

# Adding job roles which correspond to staff
import csv
with open('dict_role.csv') as f:
   role_dict = dict(filter(None, csv.reader(f)))
df2['Sender_Role'] = df2['From'].map(role_dict)
df2['Receiver_Role'] = df2['To'].map(role_dict)
df2 = df2[['Date','From','To','Sender_Role','Receiver_Role','content','Included_In_Email']]
del role_dict

# Cleaning content column
df2['content'] = df2['content'].str.rsplit('Subject: ').str[-1] 
df2['content'] = df2['content'].str.rsplit(' --------------------------- ').str[-1] 

# Condensing records into one line per email exchange, adding weights
Weighted = df2.groupby(['From', 'To']).count()

# Adding weight column, removing redundant columns, splitting indexed column
Weighted['Weight'] = Weighted['Date']
Weighted = 
Weighted.drop(['Date','Sender_Role','Receiver_Role','content','Included_In_Email'], 1)
Weighted.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Re-adding job-roles to staff
with open('dict_role.csv') as f:
   role_dict = dict(filter(None, csv.reader(f)))
Weighted['Sender_Role'] = Weighted['From'].map(role_dict)
del role_dict

# Dropping exchanges with a weight of <= x, or no identifiable role
Weighted2 = Weighted[~(Weighted['Weight'] <=3)]
Weighted2 = Weighted.dropna()
```

Two dictionaries are used in the script (for matching job-roles and changing multiple emails for the same person), and can be found [here](https://github.com/Laurie-Bamber/Enron_Corpus).